# How to output all class objects in console?

Tags: c#

I have a class Student and i want to output every student name, but dont know how to do this.

I have tried to make this using cycle.

```
class Student
{
    public int score;
    public string name;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student first = new Student
        {
            name = "Alex",
            score = 190
        };

        Student second = new Student
        {
            name = "Misha",
            score = 177
        };
        //+8 students
    }
```

I expect some method in the class, which will output every student name.

Comment: You might want to look into [arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm) or a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections)

Comment: I was going to suggest reflection, but I think OP just wrote the title badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list of object, add the objects in and then iterate through the list.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
```

Then add the object to the list this way...

```
students.Add(first);
//Do this for every student object
```

Then do whatever you want with it

```
foreach (var student in students)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(i.name + " " + i.score); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, declare a collection that will hold the reference to all Student objects.

Lets use an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) for this example.

```
// add more students if needed.
var students = new Student[] {  new Student
                                    {
                                        name = "Alex",
                                        score = 190
                                    },
                                    new Student
                                    {
                                        name = "Misha",
                                        score = 177
                                    }};

foreach (var s in students)
{
    Console.Write($"Student name is {s.name}");
}
```

After we have the array, lets loop over the students using [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in):

```
foreach(var s in students)
{
   Console.Write($"Student name is {s.name}");
}
```